# Cant get my circle to move in Python

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to get a simple pygame drawn circle to move by changing its Y axis when UP arrow key is pressed, but it doesnt work, heres my code:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([500, 500])
circle = pygame.draw.circle(screen, [255,255,255],[100,100], 10, 0)
pygame.display.update()


while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit(0)
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                circle.y = circle.y + 1
                pygame.display.flip()
```

I hope you can help! Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: @AmirHosseinMehrvarzi rather than just linking to that, could you clarify which part of that you think this question violates?

Comment: Dear Jordan. Before asking any question, please read the help page completely. your question is not constructive unfortunately. >Some subjective questions are allowed, but “subjective” does not mean “anything goes”. All subjective questions are expected to be constructive. What does that mean? Constructive subjective questions

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to draw your circle in the new location. And don't forget to erase the old one.

Answer (score 0):

working version:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([500, 500])
circle = pygame.draw.circle(screen, [255,255,255],[100,100], 10, 0)
pygame.display.update()


while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit(0)
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                eraser = pygame.draw.circle(screen, [0,0,0],[100,circle.y], 20, 0) #revision
                circle = pygame.draw.circle(screen, [255,255,255],[100,circle.y+1], 10, 0)
                pygame.display.flip()
```

The revision simply draws over the old area before then drawing a new circle in the new location.

Answer (score 0):

here you go:

```
import pygame,sys
from pygame.locals import *
from pygame.constants import K_UP, K_DOWN

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([500,500])
white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)

class Circle(object):
    def __init__(self,posy):
        self.y = posy   
        def update(self):
        key=pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.y -= 1
        if key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.y += 1

    def draw(self):
        circle = pygame.draw.circle(screen,white,(100,self.y),10,0)

def main():
    newcircle = Circle(100)
    while True:
        screen.fill(black)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        newcircle.update()
        newcircle.draw()
        pygame.display.update()
    pygame.quit()
main()
```